# system:node fails to get secrets from apiserver via curl

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, kube-apiserver, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-rbac

I'm doing some POC for security research, trying to access namespace secrets directly from a worker node. I have a cluster on GKE running Kubernetes 1.20

I'm running the following command from a worker (none-master) node:

```sh
curl -v $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/ \
  --cacert /etc/srv/kubernetes/pki/ca-certificates.crt \
  --cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client.crt \
  --key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client.key
```

And it works fine.

However, trying to get secrets fails:

```sh
curl -v $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/ \
  --cacert /etc/srv/kubernetes/pki/ca-certificates.crt \
  --cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client.crt \
  --key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client.key
```

```json
{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "secrets is forbidden: User \"system:node:gke-XXX--YYY\" cannot list resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"pencil\": No Object name found",
"reason": "Forbidden",
"details": {
  "kind": "secrets"
},
"code": 403
```

Looking at the documentation, I see that kubelet running on node should be able to access secrets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/node/

And from my understanding, the authorization is backed by the `ClusterRole` `system:node`. Looking at it I do see it has the role to `get` secrets:

```sh
% kubectl get clusterrole system:node -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "kind": "ClusterRole",
...
        {
            "apiGroups": [
                ""
            ],
            "resources": [
                "configmaps",
                "secrets"
            ],
            "verbs": [
                "get",
                "list",
                "watch"
            ]
        },
...
    ]
}
```

And some more relevant documentation for communication between kubelet and kube-apiserver: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#node-to-control-plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/node/node_authorizer.go#L198), I found the meaning of `No Object name found` error - secrets or configmaps must be named in order to be retrieved. As suggested by the documentation, they can be retrieved if mapped to the node in question by some pod.

Therefore assuming some secret `server-password` is used by some pod in my node, following command worked as expected:

```sh
curl -v $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/server-password \
  --cacert /etc/srv/kubernetes/pki/ca-certificates.crt \
  --cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client.crt \
  --key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client.key
```

Also apparently `kubectl` can be used just as simply, its the one creating the certificates at `/var/lib/kubelet/pki` in the first place.

```sh
kubectl --kubeconfig /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig -n default get secret server-password -o json
```

Answer (score 3):

- I think the certificates location you are giving is incorrect. I have tried the same on my plain kubernetes cluster with following certificates and it worked fine.

```
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets
```

Comment: You sure you are seeing this on a worker node? On worker the path `/etc/kubernetes/pki` doesn't exist and I can't find any file named `apiserver-kubelet-client.crt` in the file system

Comment: Verified that by design these certificates should not exist on non-master nodes. Node only has kubelet client certificate to communicate to kube-apiserver with.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

Because the access to secrets is permitted(normally) via service account. You need to find the service account token mounted on a pod running on the node. For this you may try to dig into "magical" /proc folder on the node. If you can access the service account token mounted on the pod and that service account has the permission to access secrets then only the secrets can be accessed from the nodes.

Comment: This contradicts the documentation. Digging in deeper, I found that indeed you're limited by which secrets you can read, but read them you can, without anything except the node client certificate.